# Tryingto style a faceted search results but keyword searches are not getting styled

Tags: drupal, search, customization, drupal-7, faceted-search

The faceted search is set up to filter by 4 vocabs each with 100+ terms inside. These vocabs are only attached to a specific content type.

When using faceted search i can use the guided search to narrow down my results and these can be styled. When i enter a keyword such as taxonomy%609 which is an argument which is issued when i click on the related taxonomy, the style is applied because the results are outputted with the classes used in the results view (semanticviews-view-fields--VIEW-NAME.tpl.php), a basic keyword search such as "the" brings up loads of results but they are styled using ( what seems to be ) the classes of a basic search results page.

Why is this happening? Is there a tpl i can call to overwrite this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

The [Devel Themer module](https://drupal.org/project/devel_themer) is useful for determining how to override a particular part of a site. It will tell you what theme functions or template files are currently being used and what your options are for overriding them.

Comment: Thanks for that - it's a very useful module. We actually solved the issue by changing the option in the Faceted Search module to not use the "extracts" display style. With this unticked, it routes any keyword searches through the normal template